# HTML form file upload to Google Drive and save URL to google sheet

Tags: html, forms, file, upload, google-sheets

I'm new to the world of google scripting, and have found some great tutorials on how to either:
i Upload a file to Google Drive with HTML form
ii Append new rows to a google sheet.

Essentially I am trying to to write a basic HTML form that collects a few text fields and file attachment, where the file attachment is uploaded to my google drive and the URL along with the other form text fields are appended a Google Sheet.

Here is the HTML form I am working with (based on a tutorial I found):

```
<!-- Include the Google CSS package -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

<!-- You can also include your own CSS styles -->
<style>
  form { margin: 40px auto; }
  input { display:inline-block; margin: 20px; }
</style>

<script>

  // The function will be called after the form is submitted
  function uploadFile() {
    document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = "Uploading File..";
    google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
       .uploadFiles(document.getElementById("labnol"));
    return false;
  }

  // This function will be called after the Google Script has executed
  function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('labnol').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
  }

</script>

<!-- This is the HTML form -->
<form id="labnol">

  <!-- Text input fields -->
  <input type="text" id="nameField" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
  <input type="email" id="emailField" name="myEmail" placeholder="Your email..">

  <!-- File input filed -->
  <input type="file" name="myFile">

  <!-- The submit button. It calls the server side function uploadfiles() on click -->
  <input type="submit" id="uploadFile" value="Upload File"
         onclick="this.value='Uploading..';uploadFile();">

</form>

<!-- Here the results of the form submission will be displayed -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

And here is the google script (again, based on a useful tutorial on a blog)

```
/* The script is deployed as a web app and renders the form */
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  // This is important as file upload fail in IFRAME Sandbox mode.
}

/* This function will process the submitted form */
function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    /* Name of the Drive folder where the files should be saved */
    var dropbox = "Test Form Submissions";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    /* Find the folder, create if the folder does not exist */
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    } 

    /* Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob */
    var blob = form.myFile;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);

    //Allocate variables for submissions in sheet
    var namerecord = form.myName;
    var emailrecord = form.myEmail;

    /* Set the file description as the name of the uploader */
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    /* Return the download URL of the file once its on Google Drive */
    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

    var uploadURL = file.getUrl();


  //

  } catch (error) {

    /* If there's an error, show the error message */
    return error.toString();
  }

        //Open spreadsheet based on URL
  var googsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17fuu1vUuxgCgs1TpSGpWDNxMHX3AEFscmjX156HQ5_U/edit?usp=sharing');
  Logger.log(googsheet.getName());

  var sheet = googsheet.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow(["James", "jim", "abc"]);



}
```

My intuition was simply to slip some lines of code in to add the form data to the specified sheet but it's not working and I must be doing something wrong :S

Any advice would be greatly appreciated to an ignorant Business Analyst new to web programming :/

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to learn troubleshooting techniques.  [Google Doc - Troubleshooting](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14BjSnTnzj7w9LV5id4Hc2z3jOYkH2hZduwLDxcYssWo/edit)  Right now, you're basically asking for code review, not help with a specific error or issue.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, and with this link solved my issue :

this a update from google script example for upload file with google sheets and Macros.

1. In the line in the HTML defining the submit button, change `id="uploadFile"` to `id="uploadFileButton"` (there was possibly a collision between the id of the submit button and the function `uploadFile()`)
2. and also change the onclick trigger by adding an extra return false: 
   `onclick="this.value='Uploading..';uploadFile();return false;"`
3. Correspondingly, in the code defining the uploadFile() function, change

   ```
   document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = "Uploading File..";
   ```

   to

   ```
   document.getElementById('uploadFileButton').value = "Uploading File..";
   ```

a complete thread link: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6177

Regards From Venezuela

NOTE: Sorry for my bad English